# Android Studio - JAVA - TIC TAC TOE

Tags: java, android

I have made my first tic tac toe game on android, but I have found a bug and I dont know how to fix it.

When player1 wins with last turn in certain combinations like bottom row horizontal or first vertical row then it pops - It is a draw - when there is winner.

Here I define my variables.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// 0 yellow ; 1 red;
int activePlayer = 0;

boolean gameIsActive = true;

// 2 unplayed;
int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
int[][] winningPositions = {
        {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, //hor
        {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, // ver
        {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}
};         // dia
```

Here is my logic behind it. I know that fixing need to be made somewhere after the comment: checking for the winner! Because it does not go trough if part but goes into else and pops - it is a draw.

full code as requested JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// 0 yellow ; 1 red;
int activePlayer = 0;
boolean gameIsActive = true;
// 2 unplayed;
int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
int[][] winningPositions = {
        {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, //hor
        {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, // ver
        {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}
};         // dia
public void dropIn (View view) {
    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());
    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2  && gameIsActive) {
        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;
        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
        if (activePlayer == 0) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;
        } else {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }
        counter.animate()
                .translationYBy(1000f)
                .rotation(360)
                .setDuration(500);
        //checking for the winner
        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] ==      gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] !=2 ) {
                //Someone has won
                gameIsActive = false;
                String winner = "Red";
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){
                    winner = "Yellow";
                }
                TextView winnerMsg = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.winnerMsg);
                winnerMsg.setText(winner + " has won!");
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                boolean gameIsOver = true;
                for (int counterState : gameState ) {
                    if (counterState == 2) {
                        gameIsOver = false;
                    }
                }
                if (gameIsOver) {
                    TextView winnerMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMsg);
                    winnerMsg.setText("It is a DRAW!");
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void playAgain(View view) {
    gameIsActive = true;
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    activePlayer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {
        gameState[i] = 2;
    }
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

and XML:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6"/>>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="7"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8"/>
</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#deed17"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/winnerMsg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play Again!"
        android:id="@+id/playBtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="playAgain" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste your full file as it is not clear what you are doing in rest of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your for loop, you are checking all possible win conditions and when it finds one, it continues through the rest of the win conditions. If you just put a break at the end of your code

```
 for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) 
    {
        if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                gameState[winningPosition[0]] !=2 ) 
        {
            //Someone has won
            gameIsActive = false;

            String winner = "Red";
            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) 
            {
                winner = "Yellow";
            }
            TextView winnerMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMsg);
            winnerMsg.setText(winner + " has won!");
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
```

That might do it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. If you liked the answer, could you please upvote it? Thanks.

Comment: I need bit more reputation to do that, sry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code instead of above 'if condition' to get the concept clear:-

```java
    int player1=0, player2=0;     

    for(int i=0; i< winningPosition.length; i++) {
             if (gameState[winningPosition[i]] == 0) {
                 player1++;
             } else if (gameState[winningPosition[i]] == 1) {
                 player2++;
             }
         }

    if (player1==3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Yellow Won!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (player2==3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Red Won!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```